# ScrollPane en Java Swing. Duda desplazamiento barra scroll

Tags: java, java-swing, jpanel

Tengo una duda sobre las barras de `scroll` en los `scrollPane`.

Actualmente tengo un `scrollPane` y dentro un `jPanel` en el que de manera dinámica voy añadiendo botones y textArea con texto. La cuestión es que, cuando añado varios botones y se activa la barra de `scroll`, aparece en una posición abajo del todo del panel en lugar de lo lógico, que sería arriba del panel para poder desplazarme por mis botones hacia abajo ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la barra de desplazamiento del `scrollPane` salga por defecto arriba en lugar de abajo?

[image: Aqui les muestro en la posicion que sale por defecto.-]

El problema esta en el txtArea, si pongo el txtArea vacío o con una sola letra sale arriba...
Gracias

Comment: Si no pones tu código poco se te puede ayudar

Comment: Bueno, la pregunta es si existe alguna propiedad en swing que haga que la barra del scrollPane se ponga por defecto en la posición de arriba, en lugar de que salga abajo. Un saludo.

Comment: Probaste dándole el foco a un elemento que esté _arriba_?

Comment: Sí, pero he metido al primer componente un requestFocus() pero nada, la scrollBar sigue abajo, El problema es causado por el textArea que tengo, pero necesito tenerlo. Ya probé tambien metiendo el textArea en un panel, pero ocurre el mismo comportamiento. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, los componentes `JTextArea` son los que producen ese comportamiento sobre el desplazamiento automático de la barra y sucede cuando se inicializan con texto o al usarse un `append` o `setText`.

Honestamente desconozco puntualmente la razón, pero es algo relacionado con el '*caret*' del componente; puede llegar a ser útil si se evita dicho desplazamiento con la propiedad [`setUpdatePolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/DefaultCaret.html#setUpdatePolicy(int)) de la clase [`DefaultCaret`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/DefaultCaret.html).

Teniendo concretamente esta solución:

```
private void fill() {
  int compCount=10;
  for(int i=0;i<compCount;i++) {
    JButton B=new JButton("Button #"+(i+1));
    JTextArea TA=new JTextArea("Text Area #"+(i+1));
    DefaultCaret caret=new DefaultCaret();//Nueva instancia del caret
    caret.setBlinkRate(500);
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);//Evita el scroll hacia abajo
    TA.setCaret(caret);//Cada area de texto con el nuevo caret
    components.add(B);
    components.add(TA);
  }
}
```

**Nota:**
Los valores permitidos son `NEVER_UPDATE`, `ALWAYS_UPDATE` y `UPDATE_WHEN_ON_EDT`. Por defecto `UPDATE_WHEN_ON_EDT` es el valor predefinido.

---

***¡Feliz 2022 a toda la comunidad SOes!***

Answer (score 0):

Salu2. tengo un JScrollbar y sobre el tengo un jpanel, la solución desde el gráfico en diseño de java con netbeans la obtuve empequeñeciendo de izq a derecha el jpanel.

es decir, cuando agregas el jpanel al scroll, el lo toma completo en sus dimensiones, es como si opacara la barras vert y horz de desplazamiento, por lo cual al empequeñecer tanto en vertical y horizontal, un poco al jpanel, deberían aparecerte ambas en la vista previa y posterior a eso, desde propiedades puedes configurar que NEVER o ALWAYS aparezcan las barras de desplza... me pasaba igual, se me iba al piso, corría unos centímetros hacia arriba y retornaba abajo. es bloqueo del jpanel agregado.

en edicion debes correr el jpanel de tal manera que logres ver ambas barras estando configuradas por defecto en as need, luego de que veas el desplazameinto normal de las barras con el jpanel agregado, puedes ocultar la hort o vert o según quieras hacer

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/339433)